# Media Query styles are not been applied on desktop and tablet but works fine on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm designing a multi-column page using mobile first design. So my default design is for mobile, and I'm using media queries to scale the design up to tablet and mobile version. I included my meta tag in my index.html document but my media queries styles are not being applied to tablet and desktop view on chrome dev tools and even on the live webpage. I'm using Sass.

Please I need help to know why my code is not working.

```
 #app-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid $blue-color;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 3%;
    display: block;

      .shirt-container {
         width: 90%;
         border: 1px solid $pink-color;
         margin: 10% auto;
         height: 60vh;
         display: block;
      }
   } 

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #app-container {
         display: inline-block;

       .shirt-container {
           width: 50%;
           display: inline-block;
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try `@media (max-width: 480px)`

Comment: @blex Ahh, yeah. Mobile first. Didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: It works [on here](https://jsfiddle.net/a7c1jjdu/). Do you have a live page we could look at, or could you provide an example on JS Fiddle? I don't see anything wrong with the CSS you showed us.

Comment: What is your compiled CSS showing for your media query? If nothing is changing when you make any edits, then it could mean that you have a syntax error somewhere in your Sass that must be fixed first.